# Bash; check if a folder exist while the folders are numbered

Tags: bash, scripting

I have a series of folders (A1, A2, ...) and some subfolders, but I only need to check the subfolders which follow this pattern `0$n_st*` and I do not need to check the rest of the subfolders:

```
A1/
        01_stjhs_lkk/
        02_stlkd_ooe/
        03_stoie_akwe/
        ...
A2/
        01_stpw_awq/
        02_stoe_iwoq/
        03_stak_weri/
        ...
...
```

I want to find the subfolder which has largest number (`0$n`) (the number of subfolders varies among different folders), then go to the subfolder and `grep` something and repeat the process over other folders (A1, A2, ...) here is my script which does not work (seems the `if` condition has some problem)

```
for dd in */; do 
   cd "$dd" # A1, A2,...
       for num in {8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1}; do
               if [  -d 0${num}_st* ]; then
                  echo "0${num}_st*"
                  cd "0${num}_st*"
                  echo $(grep -i 'xyz       f' 04_*.log) #grep this line from log file
                  break
               fi
               cd ..
       done
       cd ..
done
```

Comment: It's not really clear what you want your script to do. The braces seem unnecessary; you can just do `for num in 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1; do` but for the immediate question, `for dir in ./[0-9]*/; do : nothing; done` will end up with the alphabetically last folder in `$dir` after the end of the loop. If they all have the same number of digits, that will also be the numerically largest.

Comment: @tripleee thank you. I have many folders with these subfolders, which start with 0, but there are other subfolders there that I have nothing to do with them, I only need the largest folder which starts with 0, grep something and move to another folder and repeat the same process.

Comment: So `grep -i 'xyz       f' "$dir"/04_*.log` after the loop would do what you want (and avoid the [useless use of `echo`](https://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#echo))? Apparently you'll want to change the wildcard in the `for` loop to `0[0-9]_st*/` too. If not, please [edit] to clarify what your precise requirements are; probably also review the guidance for providing a [mre].

Comment: grep in the folder which has the largest number (0$n), I will complete the script.

Comment: This is still not well-defined. Do you mean the biggest out of all of `A?/0[0-9]_st*` or loop over the `A[0-9]` folders and find the biggest subdirectory which matches the wildcard within each?

Comment: the largest among the subfolders which their names start with 0

Comment: I think your approach doesn't seem to deal with the case that you have a subfolder named `025_xxxx_yyy`, because you regard only a single digit after the `0`.

Comment: @user1934428 actually, I am looking for this pattern `0$n_st*`, where `$n` may have two digits, too.

Comment: But in your code, `num` is always a single digit! And if you don't specify such crucial details, you can't expect helpful solutions. For instance, the (otherwise excellent) answer by _tripleee_ also is tailored to single digits only. With a single digit, you can rely on alphabetical, if the number of digits vary, you need a numeric sort.

Comment: Sorry for confusing script, I used one digit just to give a short example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The immediate problem is that `if [ -d ... ]` will produce a syntax error if `...` is a wildcard which matches more than one file. You can work around this in various ways, but probably the simplest which matches your (vague) requirements is something like

```
for dd in */; do
    for dir in "$dd"/0[0-9]_st*/; do
        : nothing
    done
    # the variable `$dir` will now contain the alphabetically last match
    grep -i 'xyz       f' "$dir"/04_*.log
done
```

If the directories contain different numbers of digits in their names, sorting them alphabetically will not work (2 will come after 19) but your examples only show names with two digits in all cases so let's assume that's representative.

Demo: https://ideone.com/1N2Iui

Here's a variation which exhibits a different way to find the biggest number by using `sort -n` and which thus should work for directories with variable numbers of digits, too.

```
for dd in */; do
    biggest=$(printf '%s\n' "$dd"/0*_st*/ | sort -d / -k2,2n | tail -n 1)
    grep -i 'xyz       f' "$biggest"/04_*.log
done
```

Because the wildcards already end with `/`, the `/` after e.g. `"$dd"/` is strictly speaking redundant, but harmless. You can take it out (at the cost of some legibility) if it disturbs you (or you are on a weird system where double slashes have a special meaning to the file system).

Comment: Thank you. what about the rest of subfolders that I do have anything to do with them? they will be sorted out? How should I `cd` to the largest folder to perform the `grep`?

Comment: `grep` accepts a fie name with a directory just fine, there's no need to `cd`.

Comment: I don't understand *"what about the rest of subfolders that I do have anything to do with them?"* If there are directories which do not match the wildcard, they will be ignored entirely.

Comment: The folders that I need are the one that follow this pattern `0$n_st*`, there are other folders which does not fit into this criterion.

Comment: Let me try your script

Comment: I think one `/` must be removed besides that, what do you understand from this message?  `grep: /0[0-9]_st*//04_*.log: No such file or directory`

Comment: Looks like you forgot to specify `dd`, or populated it with an empty string.  The duplicate slashes are harmless as such, but easy to avoid if you like (just take out the slash in `for dir in "$dd"0[0-9]_st*` and similiarly for the `grep` command).

Comment: Updated with a variation which works with `sort -n | tail` instead of relying on the shell's built-in alphabetic sort order for wildcard expansions.

Answer (score 0):

Suggesting `find` command.

```
find . -type d -printf "%f\n" |grep "^0"|sort -n|tail -n1
```

Notice this find command scans recursively **all** directories under current directory.

In order to limit `find` command to specific directories `dir1` `dir2` you need to specify them before `-type` option.

```
find dir1 dir2 -type d -printf "%f\n" |grep "^0"|sort -n|tail -n1
```

### Explanation

- `find . -type d`
  Prints all all the directories and subdirectories under current directory
- `find . -type d -printf "%f\n"`
  Prints only the directory name, not the directory path.
- `grep "^0"`
  Filter only directory names starting with `0`

  If matching more than required directories,
  possibly refine `grep` filter: `grep "^0[[:digit:]]\+_"` as well.
- `sort -n`
  Sort directory names numerically
- `tail -n1`
  Print the last directory

Comment: Thank you. I am going to try your script.

Comment: Revised my script, please try again.

Comment: As always, `find` will traverse arbitrarily deep subdirectory structures, which is sometimes fine, and sometimes a huge pain. You can restrict this with e.g. adding `-maxdepth 2` but fundamentally, using `find` when you already know where the files are is slightly odd, and often inefficient.

Comment: Thank you so much Dudi Boy, sorry, I do not have enough reputation to upvote your solution, if you do not mind, I am going to accept tripleee solution based on chronological order.

Comment: In reply to @tripleee, internally `ls` command is implemented with `find`. And as for @Aa Aa. I up voted you. Now you can upvote me as well.

Comment: Thank you so much @DudiBoy, sorry, still I need 15 reputations :|

Comment: I have never seen a platform where `ls` is implemented on top of `find`. Can you share an example?